# Use the following definitions to give a careful proof that, for every binary string x, $(x^C)^R = (x^R)^C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $ w : \{{1...l}\} \rightarrow \{{0,1}\} $ is a binary string, the complement of $w$, denoted $w^C$, is the string of length $l$ defined by $w^C(i) = 1 - w(i)$. The reverse of $w$, denoted $w^R$, is the string of length $l$ defined by $w^R(i) = w(l + 1 - i)$. Use these definitions to give a careful proof that, for every binary string $x$, $(x^c)^R = (x^R)^C$.

I have no idea how to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that in both cases, the resulting vector $y$ satisfies $y(i)=1-x(l+1-i)$.